# How can I get json data from Action method and place it in select list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Actually my problem is I have a action method which will return JSON (list of countries) and I want to bind that data to bootstrap select list, I have found several code snippets but they are actually showing the complete country list.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can bind dropdown using jsonResult.

```
In your controller

public ActionResult getCountry()  
    {  
        DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();  
        return Json(db.Country.Select(x => new  
        {  
            CountryID = x.CountryID,  
            CountryName = x.CountryName  
        }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }
```

In your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "/Users/getCountry",  
       data: "{}",  
       success: function (data) {  
           var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Country</option>';  
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
               s += '<option value="' + data[i].CountryID + '">' + 
           data[i].CountryName + '</option>';  
           }  
           $("#CountryDropdown").html(s);  
       }  
   });  
});
```

and in your View

```
<form id="myForm">  
    <label for="CountryDropdown"><b>Departments</b></label>  
    <select class="form-control" id="CountryDropdown" 
  name="CountryDropdown"></select>  
</form>
```

Comment: Hello sir, i have a JSON of this type- ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Argentina","Armenia"]

Comment: @DONEPUDIRAJESH,it the response you are getting has not ids then how can you bind that to your dropdownlist

Comment: Just use `data[i]` for your option value and text. That should do the trick

Comment: Also this is not databinding, you are simply creating or updating a select list with the result of an ajax call